# unix2dos (or dos2unix) in ant

Tags: java, ant, dos2unix

How do I do unix2dos (or dos2unix) with ant.
I.e. I want to change the newlines from linux newlines (if any) to dos newlines

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found - it is the Ant [FixCRLF task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html).

Comment: Wow! It's the first time I can actually say "Jon Skeet saved my week!" :)

Comment: Guess, who else got their day saved (ik its 2020) :D

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in `fixcrlf` ant task on a set of files instead of using `dos2unix`.
The following example is equal to running `dos2unix` on all `*.sql` files located under the "SQL" directory:

```
<fixcrlf srcdir="${SQL}" includes="**/*.sql" eol="lf" eof="remove" />
```

[see](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html) for more details.